# How can I switch from my compiler invoking D1 to D2? I'd prefer to be using the more recent D2

Tags: d

Is there a way to get my compiler to treat my code as if it were D2 code? I'm currently using dmd-2.084.0.exe to compile, Notepad++ as a de facto IDE while I come to grips with this language.

Answer (score 2):

D1 has been deprecated in 2010 and the version number 2.084 tells you that you're using V2 of the DMD compiler. And 084 means that you're using the 84th major version of the compiler, which just has been published at 01.01.2019 and is the newest as I write this.

For completeness the last 0 is for patch releases which are published in between the bimonthly release cycle and contain just bug fixes and no new features.

What gives you the impression that you're using v1?

Comment: Because the compiler did not recognize writeln(), which as I understand is a 2.0 method, but it did recognize writefln(), which is generally the big hint that you're working with D1. Unless I'm mistaken.

Additionally, according to the official documentation, writeln() is a 2.0 method, yet when I attempt to use it in a basic "Hello, world"-style program, the compilers throws errors.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to import `std.stdio` or had another error in your program?

Comment: No, that isn't the case either. Here's the entire program: /n

`import std.stdio;

void main() {
 writefln("Hello, world!");
}`

Comment: And what error did you get with `import std.stdio; void main() { writeln("Hello, world!"); }`?

Comment: That's odd, using `writeln` worked on my machine (using dmd 2.083.1).  If you are using dmd 2.084.0 you are using D2.  I don't think dmd 2.084.0 even supports D1.

Comment: Yes there have been __84__ major releases since D1's last release in 2010.

Comment: This is the full text upon compiling - `helloe.d(4): Error: undefined identifier writeln, did you mean function writefln?
helloe.d(4): Error: function expected before (), not __error of type _error_`

Comment: This looks like sth. is wrong with your setup. Maybe you could post to D.learn or open up an issue with the full output of `dmd -v`

Comment: Maybe I don't have the right compiler installed? Or maybe I don't have D itself installed?

Comment: I found the problem. I installed D1 alongside D2, causing the conflict. For future coders: REMOVE D1!